# How to deploy NextJS + Express server

Tags: javascript, express, deployment, next.js

I have such structure of my project.

client - with FrontEnd part

server - BackEnd part (Express)

[image]

And server package.json scripts

[image]

To start NextJS + Express on localhost:

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use("/api", userRouter, categoriesRouter, catalogRouter, storageRouter, ordersRouter);
app.use(errorMiddleware);

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// if isDev === 'development'
if(isDev) {
    const start = async () => {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(process.env.DBURL, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true
            })
            app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on PORT = ${PORT}`))
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    start()
}

// if isDev === 'production'
if(!isDev) {
  // what should be here to deploy production version?
}
```

But what I should to do to deploy my server for example on Heroku. I cant find any resourse with example of nextJS + Express deployment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795433/deploying-nextjs-front-end-and-expresss-back-end-to-heroku

Comment: Hey!, did you found any solution?

Comment: Did you consider using nextjs api routes and deploying the code on Vercel? It will make the deployment much easier. Otherwise, I recommend splitting the code into two repos and deploying it separately.